# python/scrapy for dynamic content

Tags: python, scrapy

I am trying to write a python/scrapy script to get a list of ads from https://www.donedeal.ie/search/search?section=cars&adType=forsale&source=&sort=relevance%20desc&max=30&start=0, im interested in getting urls to individual ads. I found that page is making a XHR POST request to https://www.donedeal.ie/search/api/v3/find/.
Tried to write scrapy shell script to try my idea:

```
from scrapy.http import FormRequest
url = 'https://www.donedeal.ie/search/api/v3/find/'
payload = {'section': "cars", 'adType': "forsale", 'source': "", 'sort': "relevance desc", 'area': '', 'max': '30', 'start':'0'}
req = FormRequest(url, formdata=payload)
fetch(req)
```

but i get no response. In Chrome dev tools i saw that such request gives a json response with item ids which I could use to form urls myself.

---

I tried Selenium approach as well, where it gives time for a page to load up the dynamic content but that didn't seem to work either. Completely lost at this stage :(

Comment: You may consider doing the query from a browser while using a tool like `WireShark` to ascertain what https is sending/receiving, so you could verify that your `scrapy` is not missing anything in its _payload._

Comment: So the payload that dev tools show might not be complete?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the call, the payload is almost OK.

The site you want to scrape accepts only JSON as payload so you should change your `FormRequest` to something like this:

```
import json
yield Request( url, method='POST', 
               body=json.dumps(payload), 
               headers={'Content-Type':'application/json'} )
```

This is because `FormRequest` is for simulate HTML forms (the content type is set to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`), not JSON calls.

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to create a working example with Scrapy.

However, I did come up with two other solutions for you.

In the examples below, response contains JSON data.

**Working Example #1** using **[`urllib2`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html)** — Tested with Python ***2.7.10***

```
import urllib2

url = 'https://www.donedeal.ie/search/api/v3/find/'
payload = '{"section":"cars","adType":"forsale","source":"","sort":"relevance desc","max":30,"start":0,"area":[]}'

req = urllib2.Request(url)
req.add_header('Content-Type', 'application/json')

response = urllib2.urlopen(req, payload).read()
```

**Working Example #2** using **[`requests`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/requests/)** — Tested with Python ***2.7.10*** and ***3.3.5*** and ***3.5.0***

```
import requests

url = 'https://www.donedeal.ie/search/api/v3/find/'
payload = '{"section":"cars","adType":"forsale","source":"","sort":"relevance desc","max":30,"start":0,"area":[]}'

response = requests.post(url, json=payload).content
```